# PLpgSQL: Store each record in For Loop and returns json

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to store a record or a json into an array and return a JSON from a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stat_per_day() RETURNS json AS $$
DECLARE 
RR RECORD;
SS json[];
BEGIN
  FOR RR IN (SELECT DISTINCT date 
      FROM timetable WHERE date<CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY date ASC)
  LOOP
    SELECT row_to_json(A) INTO SS FROM (SELECT RR.date as Dia, count(*) Total
    FROM dates WHERE office_date=RR.date) A;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN json_agg(SS);
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"dia":"2017-07-24","total":228}"
DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function stat_per_day() line 8 at SQL statement
```

The query is a little more complex, but the idea is to "save" each forloop query in a json array or record array( which i think do not exist ) and after loop, return a complete json from the array.

Answer (score 1):

May be you not need LOOP cycle? This task could be do using `json_build_object` function, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stat_per_day() RETURNS json AS $$
DECLARE 
SS json;
BEGIN
    select json_agg(j order by (j->>'dia')::date) from (
        SELECT json_build_object('dia', office_date, 'Total', count(*) ) as j 
        from dates
        where 
        office_date in (SELECT date FROM timetable WHERE date<CURRENT_DATE)
        group by office_date
    ) t
    into SS;

    RETURN SS;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```